# Восстановить файлы в PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Проблема следующая.

Работал как обычно вышло сообщение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все файлы проекта обнулились. Имя файлов есть, но весят все по 0 кб. Что делать? Бэкапов небыло

Answer (score 2):

Правой кнопкой на файл, ближе к нижнему краю есть Local History, выбрать Show History, возможно, там все есть.

*Впредь нужно делать бэкапы или хотя бы пользоваться системой контроля версий.*

Comment: Дружище, блин ты так выручил.